# Multi step registration form in Drupal 7 with video as a step using ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal

I'm pretty new to Drupal but I've been developing in PHP for about 8 years now. I've tried doing this using the admin UI modules but pretty much running up against a brick wall!

1. I want to make a landing page ie example.com/username (Anonymous user gets this from supplied literature).
2. User fills out their details on step 1
3. User leaves feedback on step 2
4. User watches a short video on step 3 before being able to click Next button
5. User fills out another field in step 4 and clicks finish

When this is all done, I want the user to be then registered with the Drupal site (so they don't have to do step 1 again). I know I would have to write a module for this but asking here to see if anyone knows it's possible to do with Drupal 7 before I get into the code.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to force the user to watch the video before they are allowed to continue or just assume that they've watched it and provide a 'next' button?

Comment: Hi Clive, thanks for responding. Yes user must watch the video before they can continue.

Comment: I think that will be your sticking point, everything else is pretty straight forward using Drupal. Do you have an idea how you would enforce such a thing just using standard PHP/HTML/Javascript? I'm drawing a bit of a blank

Comment: Yes I did it through JQuery on a normal PHP site before. Just did a countdown. There are other ways to do it from the video sending a message to the page when it's finished as well. I've been learning Drupal for the last few weeks though and it seems to be able to do all the things I need for the site so would like to go down that road.

Comment: Good stuff, it's definitely possible I'll post some info in an answer there's probably a bit much to go in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a stroke of luck I just came across [this post on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/999420) in which someone has gone through the whole process of converting the Drupal 7 registration form into a multistep one, so this would be a great place to start (they've even posted a lot of the code you'll need).

The basic principle is to implement `hook_form_user_register_form_alter` in your module and convert the form into a multistep one. One of your steps would then be to show the video and implement the jQuery as you've mentioned in your comment. I won't go into any more detail as it would just be regurgitating what's in the link above, but also check out the [Form API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7), it'll help when doing this.

By the way if you're new to coding in Drupal grab the [Examples module](http://www.drupal.org/project/examples), it's a very valuable resource.

Hope that helps

Comment: Can't believe I never came across that Clive! Will be a great place to start... Many thanks mate!! :D