# How to achieve multistep in Drupal 7 default user registration form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, user-registration, drupal-forms

I need to create a user registration form in Drupal 7. My requirement is as follows:-

1. I want to use the default Drupal 7 User Registration Form i.e admin/config/people/accounts
2. Form must appear in popup/modal when user click on "Create new account" in User Login Form
3. Form should be Multistep i.e there will be 3/4 steps of filling the form.
4. Customize the form in such a way that UserName, Password and Email
   appears on last step of the form.

Please let me know if it is possible in Drupal 7 default user registration form and how?

Answer (score 4):

Below are some references to follow:

- [Step by step tutorial](http://grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7).
- [This awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814517/863380) from Clive.
- Also, consider using [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) and [Profile2 registration path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module for better registration forms customization.

Comment: Thanks for your Reference. So there is no way to use any existing module to make the user registration form as multistep. Actually I want to use most of the default features of Drupal7 or existing any modules contributed by developers .